# Is there a lens adapter for a Pentax lens to a Canon AE-1?

Tags: lens, film, adapter, camera

I have a Pentax my with a zoom lens, and I also have a Canon AE-1 Program. which is my all time fave. I would like to use the Pentax zoom lens on my Canon. Is there an adapter to make that possible? And where would it be available? If item is possible, what would something like this run...or would it be cheaper to just buy a zoom lens for my Canon?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: Do you mean a *Pentax ME* ?  If so you would need a Pentax K to Canon FD mount adapter.  I do not know of such an adapter available at present and cannot recall ever hearing of one.

Comment: @StephenG, I'd say post that as an answer, rather than a comment. Regardless of which Pentax mount the lens might be, finding adapters to Canon FD rather than Canon EOS is going to be tough.

Comment: @inkista If the OP confirms they have a Pentax ME (or specifies another Pentax K mount body) I'll post it as an answer.  But now it's just speculative and I think it's inappropriate as an answer.

Comment: @Dawn What kind of Pentax camera do you have? There are a number of different Pentax mounts used by different Pentax cameras.

Comment: I would suggest that buying a new zoom lens for your Canon will be both easier and more satisfactory in the long run. You don't mention which zoom lens, but if it's probably not the newest or best, and zooms have improved a lot over the years.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the mount of your Pentax camera.

- Finding a ready-made solution to adapt to Pentax K mount to Canon FD
  is basically not something you're going to find.
- If you have a thread-mount M42 Pentax camera, then you can find
  adapter rings to FD.
- And as there are Pentax 6x7 to M42 adapters, you could stack adapters
  if your Pentax is 6x7.